# Show / Hide list items in Angular in the HTML angular

Tags: html, angular, angular9

I have a list of 4 items, the first 2 visible and the last 2 hidden.
And a "show more / less" button that toggles the visibility of the last 2 items.

```
<ol>
  <li *ngFor="let errorList of errorItems | slice: 0:count">
    <p>{{ errorList }}</p>
  </li>
</ol>
<p *ngIf="errorItems.length > 2" (click)="viewMoreClicked()">view more details</p>
```

I need view more and view less

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, post what you've tried.

P.S. Your `*ngIf` is not going to let you do what you described, you should toggle a "isVisible" property instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
<ol>
  <li *ngFor="let type of items | slice: 0:count">
    <p>{{ type?.value }}</p>
  </li>
</ol>
<p *ngIf="items.length > 2 && count == 2" (click)='count=items.length'>view more details</p>
<p *ngIf="count != 2" (click)='count=2'>view less details</p>

count = 2;
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b4gcwb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)